# Is there an OGC standard for data synchronization?

Tags: ogc, change-detection

ESRI provides two solutions that facilitate synchronization.  They are Editor Tracking for Feature Services (http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/windows/editor-tracking-for-feature-services.htm), which tracks who and when an edit was made, and a built-in way of assigning a UUID to a feature.  Are there any OGC standards which address change tracking in a similar (or better) way?

Comment: How does assigning a UUID to a feature help with tracking who did an update?

Comment: There are four OGC interface standards that include a transactional component (WFS-T, WCS-T, SOS, and CSW), allowing changes (Insert, Update, Delete) to data and objects.

Comment: Good question, @mntoken!  I neglect to mention my goal of synchronization.  I want to keep a subset of the spatial data locally by pulling in changes and knowing the id uniquely.  I will update the question.

Comment: @nmtoken, thanks for tagging but I'm familar with WFS-T and it's not what I'm looking for (or maybe I was wrong to delete them).  I don't want to modify the data but I do want the underlying DB to auto-assign UUID and timestamp information.  I know MSSQL, Oracle and maybe PostgreSQL have solutions but I'm not aware of any OGC standards that might exist around this.  Perhaps WFS-T addresses that and I just missed it?  Or perhaps you're saying that's as close as it gets?

Comment: I think it all depends on what you mean by `OGC standards that might exist around this`  OGC standards are interfaces standards that deal with how to access data (let's forget about SOS for the moment) through HTTP/SOAP etc network protocols, they don't generally tell you how to store/structure data, what id's to assign or how to deal with auditing.  Auditing is left up to you and probably best done in a database.  Some transactional components specify how to pass user credentials and others others aren't specific.  It is left up to the server software to determine the validity of any action.

Comment: List of OGC standards http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is does not contain such service. There is something about versioning in WFS 1.1.0 http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=8339 but as far as I know nodody is using it.